# When are ASP.NET code blocks, e.g., <%= %> executed in the page lifecycle?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

When I am databinding an entire page, I will do something like this:

Blah blah...

```
<%# SomeProperty == "GoodBye" ? "See you later" : "Hello" %>
```

And that works beatifully. However, often I will not use databinding for an entire page and write things the "clasic" ASP.NET way. E.g., in the code behind I will have something like:

```
lblSomeMessage.Text = SomeProperty == "GoodBye" ? "See you later" : "Hello";
```

And then .aspx would have

```
<asp:label runat="server" id="lblSomeMessage"/>
```

But what I want to do *both*...sort of. What I would like to do is not use databinding syntax but instead a code block:

```
<%= SomeProperty == "GoodBye" ? "See you later" : "Hello" %>
^^^^
```

Noe the output tag syntax. Now, the question is, when will this tag actually be evaluated? Suppose I don't set the SomeProperty property until the OnPreRender event. Is that too late? In my testing I actually did this:

```
<%= SomeProperty == "GoodBye" ? + new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString() : "OH NO!" %>
```

And according to the stacktrace:

> ASP.webform1_aspx.__Renderform1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control
>   parameterContainer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)    at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)...

It happens during render, which is perfect. But is this guaranteed? Any gotchas to this rule?

Comment: fyi: use `<%:` instead of `<%=` whenever you can. It automatically html-encodes the output, and you can even change the encoding engine if you want.

Comment: Agreed. In this particular case I am outputting a static string, but point well taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed to be `Render`.

"An embedded code block is server code that executes during the page's render phase." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that :)