# Populating the SQLDatasource SelectCommand

Tags: c#, webforms, sqldatasource, selectcommand

How do I take this string and drop it into the select command?

```
    String SqlC = "select * from dbo.FindIt where " + SqlStr;
```

The object is to populate the SelectCommand:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:M3ConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand = SqlC >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a SelectCommand in code behind which works identically to creating one in the SQLDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991177/creating-a-selectcommand-in-code-behind-which-works-identically-to-creating-one)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var runx = Request.QueryString.GetValues("run") != null ? Request.QueryString.GetValues("run")[0] : "";
    if (runx != "") {
       var sqlStr = "RUN= '" + Runx + "'";
       var sqlC = "select * from dbo.FindIt where " + sqlStr;
       SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sqlC;
    }
    else {
       // TODO: Handle this situation.
    }
}
```

Comment: If I go to the Design tab and double click the form, it created a Page_Load script. but I get the error "the name SqlC does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Start of the page
```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
    String Runx = Request.QueryString.GetValues("run") != null ? Request.QueryString.GetValues("run")[0] : "";

    if (Runx != "") {
        SqlStr = "RUN= '" + Runx + "'";
    }

    String SqlC = "select * from dbo.FindIt where " + SqlStr;
    %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = SqlC;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Juliemac Please see my revision. Can you simply move all of that logic into the `Page_Load` method?

Comment: That was it. Perfect!